# SDL обработчик событий

Tags: c++, sdl

Решил перейти на SDL с инициализацией разобрался благо материал много. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как на SDL обрабатывать события:

1. нажатие клавиш клавиатуры;
2. мышь (движение,нажатие).

Comment: Проблема в том что не где не объеснается а только идёт в вскользь пару слов не более

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все предельно просто:

```
SDL_Event event; // Создаем структуру событий
bool running = true; // Работает ли приложение

...

while(running){ // Пока работает
  if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){ // Если что-то случилось (нажата клавиша и тд)
    switch(event.type){ // Смотрим, что за событие
      case SDL_QUIT: running = false; break; // Окно хотят закрыть, выходим
      case SDL_KEYDOWN: // Нажата клавиша
        switch(event.key.keysym.sym){ // Какая?
          case SDLK_q: running = false; break; // Тут коды всех клавиш тут: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Scancode
        }
       break;
       case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: // Нажата клавиша
         int x, y;
         SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y); // Получить координаты мыши
         cout << "[SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN] " << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << "\n";
       break;
       case SDL_MOUSEMOTION: // Мышь сдвинута
         int x, y;
         x = event.motion.x; // Получить координаты мыши
         y = event.motion.y;
         cout << "[SDL_MOUSEMOTION] " << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << "\n";
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

А вот туториалы на английском по SDL2: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php , по SDL1: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/

**UPD**

Где-то были и на русском. Не могу найти сейчас.

P.S. Мой код использует SDL2 (не SDL v.1!).